# Random Combination From an Array (Java)

Tags: java, arrays, random

I am creating a simple Mastermind game, where my colors are represented by numbers from 0 to 9. The program should generate a random code with length from 3 to 9 digits. I decided to use an array to hold my numbers 0 to 9, but I don't know how to generate a random number with a random length from this array. Can somebody help me please ?

Comment: You can see the answer to this question [here][1].


  [1]:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/363681/generating-random-number-in-a-range-with-java

Comment: Is the generated code allowed to contain duplicate digits?  For example, is 23389 valid?

Answer (score 1):

Use the [random number generator](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/util/Random.html):

```
Random rnd=new Random()
int x=rnd.nextInt(10)
```

Comment: Yup, i know that, but my explanation was a bit stupid. Excuse me for that. I want to have a combination from my array numbers. For example if the numbers are 0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9 I want a random combination with a random length to be generated. What you guys are giving me is a little bit diferrent.

Comment: So... put the above code in a for loop that gets one number at a time.

Answer (score 1):

Here is the sample code:

```
package testing.Tests_SO;

import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Random;

public class App14487237 {

    // creating random number generator object
    public static final Random rnd = new Random();

    public static int[] getNumber() {

        // generating array length as rundom from 3 to 9 inclusive
        int length = rnd.nextInt(7) + 3;

        // creating an array
        int[] number = new int[length];

        // filling an array with random numbers from 0 to 9 inclusive
        for(int i=0; i<number.length; ++i) {
            number[i] = rnd.nextInt(10);
        }

        // returning and array
        return number;

    }


    public static void main(String[] args) {

        // generating number 10 times and prin result
        for(int i=0; i<10; ++i) {
            System.out.println( "attempt #" + i + ": " + Arrays.toString( getNumber()  ) );
        }
    }
}
```

Here is it's output:

```
attempt #0: [0, 2, 6, 2, 5, 7, 5, 3]
attempt #1: [6, 2, 6, 6, 6, 2]
attempt #2: [8, 9, 6]
attempt #3: [6, 4, 7, 2, 1, 5, 7, 0]
attempt #4: [8, 2, 6, 7, 3, 8, 2, 9, 1]
attempt #5: [8, 6, 5, 9, 8, 8, 3, 9]
attempt #6: [6, 2, 3, 8, 6]
attempt #7: [3, 4, 6, 2]
attempt #8: [0, 5, 0, 0, 5, 8, 9, 4, 6]
attempt #9: [2, 2, 3, 3, 4, 9, 0]
```

**P.S.**

To print close:

```
int[] number;
for(int i=0; i<10; ++i) {
    number = getNumber();
    System.out.print( "attempt #" + i + ": " );
    for(int j=0; j<number.length; ++j ) {
        System.out.print(number[j]);
    }
    System.out.println();
}
```

Comment: Fantastic. Thank you very very much. Just one more thing. I want to exclude the zero number from the array. How can I do that ?

Comment: Then write `rnd.nextInt(9)+1` instead of `rnd.nextInt(10)` while generating a number.

Comment: Okay, one last question. Can you please tell me how can I print the array as a String, without any commas. For example take attempt #2 : [8, 9, 6]. I want the otput to be: 896. Thanks in advance. I hope you answer me soon = )

Answer (score 0):

Use a random number generator to determine the length of the string.

Then use a random number generator in a for loop to choose each digit from your array.

Something like this:

```
// the array of valid numbers
int[] numbers = // intialize this however you want

Random rand = new Random();

// determine random length between 3 and 9
int numLength = rand.nextInt(7) + 3;

StringBuilder output = new StringBuilder();

for (int i = 0; i < numLength; i++) {
    // use a random index to choose a number from array
    int thisNum = rand.nextInt(numbers.length);
    // append random number from array to output 
    output.append(thisNum);
}

System.out.println(output.toString());
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe what you want is part of a [random permutation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Random_permutation) of the elements in your array. This could be done in two steps.

1. Use a random generator to repeatedly swap elements in the array.

   ```
   int n = arr.length;
   for (int i = 0; i < n-1; i++) {
       int j = i + rnd.nextInt(n-i); // select element between i and n
       // swap elements i and j in the array
   }
   ```
2. Select a random length `ln` and take the elements from `0` to `ln`